# How to debug Bitcoin-qt source in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, bitcoin

I would like to start understanding the Bitcoin-qt source code.
The process of reading source code gets a lot easier by using the Eclipse IDE for C/C++, this way I can just skip to the declaration.
However, Eclipse can't find all the declaration if it doesn't compile correctly.

Now I would like to compile the Bitcoin-qt in Eclipse.
Unfortunately Eclipse can't build it. ( The original Bitcoin-qt Makefiles generate a lot of extra files )

Now I was wondering how the original Bitcoin-qt could be built in Eclipse IDE.
The original developers didn't solely use plain text editors to write the code, did they?

Comment: Don't confuse IDE and Build system. Eclipse is IDE. Unclear, what errors you get during compilation. "Original developers" use correctly configurated Eclipse and compilers.

Comment: Then my question is: How can I get the same Eclipse configuration as they did?

Comment: You may ask developers of Bitcoin-qt. But better if you do it yourself. Without binding to bitcoin-qt. First - try to compile hello-world Qt example. ONLY then try to compile bitcoin-qt and provide error log here.